# C# MVC3 Automapper class containing list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list, automapper

I´m building an automapper with the following structures:

Domain:

```
public class EnterpriseInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Installed { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public List<Msg> MsgList { get; set; }

    ...some methods...
}


public class Msg
{ 
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
 }
```

ViewModel classes:

```
public class HomeLogonHomeViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName;
    public List<SysMsg> MsgList;
}

   public class SysMsg 
   {   
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
   }
```

In the view I need to show something like:

```
Messages for company: BALBALBALBA

12/12/12 00:00 From: AAA Message: Nnonononon
12/12/12 00:00 From: AAA Message: Nnonononon
12/12/12 00:00 From: AAA Message: Nnonononon
12/12/12 00:00 From: AAA Message: Nnonononon
12/12/12 00:00 From: AAA Message: Nnonononon
12/12/12 00:00 From: AAA Message: Nnonononon
```

I´m in trouble configuring the automapper, as I have a sigle field with a single field and a list with another list. Can someone please help me...

Also, I may ask if this does indeed needs an Automapper....

[EDIT]

Working code:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseInfo, HomeLogonHomeViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

There is not need to explicit Msg to SysMsg if it was changed to be the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map EnterpriseInfo to HomeLogonHomeViewModel. I would suggest naming the Msg class in the domain to SysMsg or visa versa. Then explicity map the CompanyName member and the SysMsg member. Something like this...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EnterpriseInfo,HomeLogonHomeViewModel>()
  .ForMember(dest=>dest.CompanyName,opt=> opt.Name)
  .ForMember(dest=>dest.SysMsg, opt=>opt.SysMsg);
```

Comment: Grag, thanks. My worry is about the List<> type. Is AutoMapper going to solve MsgList automatically ?

Comment: You do not need to worry about List<> constructs. Automapper will automatically map each item in the list if the object item is mapped.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it after some doc reading. It´s working fine. Thanks.